# Cannot edit more than the last message with the arrow keys in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, chat, keyboard-shortcuts

It seems as though I can no longer use the <kbd>↑</kbd> key to edit message older than the last one.

I can still edit it by going to the menu and clicking *edit*, assuming the time limit hadn't passed yet.

Is this by design? If so, please consider reverting it, I really liked that ability.

I am using Chrome 35.0.1916.114 on Ubuntu x64.

### Steps to Reproduce

- Post two messages
- Hit the <kbd>↑</kbd> key to edit the last message
- Hit the <kbd>↑</kbd> key again to edit the second to last message.

### Expected Behavior

- Textarea is cleared, and I can edit the second to last message.

### Actual Behavior:

- Cursor jumps back to the beginning of the current message (like it would if the previous message was uneditable)

Comment: Win7 Chrome  34.0.1847.137 m works for me

Comment: Solution: don't post so much in chat. ;)

Comment: No repro Win8.1 Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m. Are you sure extensions aren't changing the behavior?

Comment: I don't have any extensions active in chat, and the one userscript I am running is run by @PeeHaa as well, and he's a no-repro too.

Comment: We've got multiple "no repro" counts here at stackexchange towers...

Comment: @MarcGravell: I suspect that this is either Linux specific or Ubuntu specific. I've confirmed this from **3 different PCs** all running Ubuntu and Chrome 35. Chrome 35 also drastically changed the look and feel of the browser, so I'm guessing it caused some BC breaks which affect the feature detection.

Comment: @SecondRikudo possibly; I have Chrome currently installing on my ubuntu rig

Comment: @MarcGravell: And you aren't witnessing this behavior?

Comment: @SecondRikudo it works fine on my ubuntu machine; no, I am not witnessing this behavior; Chrome is 35.0.1916.114

Comment: @MarcGravell: Would you mind diagnosing it with me over chat in the sandbox or something? I can't believe I'm the only one affected... I'm found on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 has [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=368100), which causes keydown to register an extra keycode (229) for every press. This confuses our "how confident are we about what they are doing?" code. I am adding an escape hatch for 229.

Comment: Here, have an extra 25 fake internet points from me!

Comment: @SecondRikudo thanks; that *totally* makes up for a couple of hours of head-banging. Of course, it also highlighted that our CDN config was broken, so it had a positive side-effect ;p

Comment: Seems to be back on both chat.so and chat.se.

Comment: @SecondRikudo do you mean the issue is back? seriously? (goes to check)

Comment: @SecondRikudo cache-breaker failure due to protocol-relative url change yesterday; fixing...

Comment: @SecondRikudo should work fine now

Comment: Indeed it does.